# Populate multiple comboboxes from 1 ienumerable

Tags: vb.net, linq, combobox, ienumerable

Good afternoon,

Is there a way to divide a ienumerable and bind all the different values to the different comboboxes.

Like you can see in the picture below: 
I got 10 comboboxes, while the input of these all come from 1 ienumerable.

[image: Overview of the application]

I do have an option to do a for each and go through the entire database, and add them to the combobox with:

```
        Dim ts As IEnumerable(Of tblLabel)
        For Each itms In ts
            CmbDescription.Items.Add(itms.Description)
            CmbLabelId.Items.Add(itms.LabelID)
            ...
        Next
```

But I wonder if I can link the different 'columns' of the Ienumerable directly to the datasource of the associated comboboxes. 
I'm searching for an option like:

```
         CmbDescription.DataSource = ts.Description
         CmbLabelId.DataSource = ts.LabelId
         ...
```

Sadly enough, this ienumerable can't be splitsed like this, as far as I can see.
Another workaround would be to create all separate ienumerables for all those comboboxes, but then it is too much code.

Any idea?

Comment: _create all seperate ienumerables for all those comboboxes, but then it is too much code_ - this exactly what you need to do. Every `ComboBox` has to have own `DataSource` which is in your case separated collection of items

Comment: Joining to @Fabio's comments. Also note that such combo boxes usually do not contain duplicates, so you normally would set each combo data source to be something like `enumerable.Select({field}).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: you could set the data source of each combo box  to the table and set each combo box datavalue and datatext fields, it will then grab only those fields for the lists.

Comment: @MaCron, when using same source/collection in different comboboxes, changing SelectedValue in one combobox will affect in others too.

Comment: No it wont, each control has its own event as well as its own Text and Value. Once the DataSource is set and the controls are bound that's what they have available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your original approach is good enough.
But if you want populate ComboBoxes by separated collection of items using `DataSource` property, then you can simply get needed collection from `IEnumerable`

```
CmbLabelId.DataSource = 
    ts.Select(function(label) label.LabelId).Distinct().ToList()
CmbDescription.DataSource = 
    ts.Select(function(label) label.Description).Distinct().ToList()
```

But in this approach you will loop `IEnumerable` as much times as how much `ComboBoxes` you have.

Here is my approach, but again want to say that your original approach is simple enough.

```
' In this class will be collected all distinct value of all columns
' Create own property for every column which used in the ComboBoxes 
' With HashSet only distinct values will be collected (thanks to @Ivan Stoev's comment)
Public Class TblLabelProperties
    Public Property LabelId As New HashSet(Of Integer)
    Public Property Description As New HashSet(Of String)
    ' Other properties/columns
End Class

' Populate collections from database
Dim ts As IEnumerable(Of tblLabel)

Dim columnsValues As TblLabelProperties = 
        ts.Aggregate(New TblLabelProperties(),
                     Function(lists, label)
                         lists.LabelId.Add(label.LabelId)
                         lists.Description.Add(label.Description)
                         'Add other properties
                         Return lists
                     End Function)

' Set DataSources of comboboxes
CmbLabelId.DataSource = columnsValues.LabelId.ToList()
CmbDescription.DataSource = columnsValues.Description.ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for all the input so far.

@Fabio: I get an error message when I try your code."System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: source     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)

Comment: Your `ts As IEnumerable(Of tblLabel)` is a `null`/Nothing. Check that your query return something or at least empty result

Comment: You're correct.  During my rework to multiple ienumerables this got removed.

Thanks for your help, I'm definitely going to use this!

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this without putting each data source to each `ComboBox` is by implementing mapping between the column name in `DataGridView.Columns` and the combo box name `ComboBox.Name`.

This can be done by using `Dictionary` so for each column name, you map to specific `ComboBox`. Then, you can do the populating by foreach or for loop.

Yet, it might still be preferable in some cases that you really take each ComboBox having its own data source